# Passing value between two view - Xcode 4.2 with storyboard

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.2, storyboard

i'm newbie in Xcode programming with storyboard.
I'm trying to passing a value (a text for a label) to "View Controller" from "SecondViewController".
Here is my code:

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)showSecondView:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Trying..");
    // The identifier used here is set on the second view controller in the UIStoryboard.
    SecondViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondIdentifier"];
    NSLog(@"Test: %@",svc.labelTest.text);  //this print NIL!!
    svc.labelTest.text = @"GOOFY!!";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)returnToFirstView:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)toTabBar:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTest;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize labelTest;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Someone could help me please?
Thank you very much!

Stefano

Answer (score 1):

if you are using storyboard, why you don't use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {`

replace your `- (IBAction)showSecondView:(id)sender {` -method

with:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondIdentifier"]) {
SecondViewController *svc = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
svc.labelTest.text = @"Goofy";
}
```

Comment: no problem :) if it helped than accept the answer not for me but other. So if they have similar problem than they can choose the best solution. It helped you and stackoverflow..